# Publish to multiple streams from vert.x mqtt client

Tags: java, graphql, mqtt, quarkus, mutiny

I have a *Quarkus* application that expose a *GraphQL* server.

This server expose a subscription that I use to have a realtime communication with the front-end.

I also have a *Vert.x* *MQTT* client (*MQTT* act as message broker).

When I call a mutation I also publish to an *MQTT* topic.

The *GraphQL* subscription should return a stream from the *MQTT* published messages.

This is the code for the *MQTT* subscription:

```
public Multi<String> subscribe(String topic) {

    BroadcastProcessor<String> processor = BroadcastProcessor.create();

    client.publishHandler(s -> {
                System.out.println(s.topicName() + " " + s.payload());
                processor.onNext(s.payload().toString());
            })
            .subscribe(topic, 2);

    return processor;
}
```

And here down the code of *GraphQL* subscription:

```
@Subscription
public Multi<String> messageCreated(String topic) {
    return client.subscribe(topic).toHotStream();
```

}

My problem is that when I publish on different topics the *GraphQL* subscription receives each message I send. (*MQTT* client subscription works correctly).

I think i'm doing something wrong with `BroadcastProcessor` and `Multi` from Mutiny.

Comment: I guess `client` refers to different types in the GraphQL subscription handler and the the message broadcaster, right? Can you update your post with the reference types?

Answer (score 0):

First *GraphQL* `Subscription` query is initiated to subscribe to *topic-1*:

1. A new `BroadcastProcessor` instance is created to bridge *MQTT* server messages to client
2. The *MQTT* client (shared instance) `publishHandler` is set with a handler using the previously (new) created `BroadcastProcessor` instance to send out items
3. The *MQTT* client `subscribe`s to the new topic
4. The `BroadcastProcessor` instance is returned which will *Quarkus* subscribe to to stream message over to client

All is well in a single invocation. The issue will arise on the next *GraphQL* subscription query to subscribe to *topic-2*:

1. Another new `BroadcastProcessor` instance is created to bridge *MQTT* server messages to client (which is fine)
2. The *MQTT* client (shared instance) `publishHandler` is **overridden** with another handler using the previously created `BroadcastProcessor` instance to send out items
3. The *MQTT* client `subscribe`s to **a new topic** (the second one)
4. The `BroadcastProcessor` instance is returned which will *Quarkus* subscribe to to stream message over to client

At the second invocation (*GraphQL* subscription query) you end up with your MQTT client having a `publishHandler` bridging messages from any *MQTT* topic you have subscribed to (in above scenario both *topic-1* and *topic-2*).

You can use a share `BroadcastProcessor` and have outgoing stream messages filtered by subscribed topic:

```
BroadcastProcessor<String> processor = BroadcastProcessor.create();
Multi<String> stream = processor.toHotStream();

client.publishHandler(s -> {
    processor.onNext(Tuple2.of(s.getTopicName(),  s.payload().toString());
});
```

Then within the *GraphQL* subscription handler:

```
@Subscription
public Multi<String> messageCreated(String topic) {
    client.subscribe(topic);
    return stream.select()
            .where(tuple -> tuple.getItem1().equals(topic));
}
```